# The product of set differences is contained in the difference of products

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $A,B,C,D$ be any sets. Prove $(A \setminus B) \times (C \setminus D) \subseteq (A \times C) \setminus ( B \times D)$. Show by way of a counterexample that the reverse inclusion is false.

What exactly does it mean by "Show by way of a counterexample that the reverse inclusion is false"? How would I go about solving this?

Comment: It means that you can find such A, B, C, D that right-hand expression will include a subset not included in a left-hand expression.

Answer (score 1):

"Show by way of counterexample" means that you have to give a counterexample, i.e. four sets $A, B, C, D$ where $(A \times C) \setminus (B \times D) \not\subseteq (A \setminus B)\times(C \setminus D)$.

Answer (score 1):

It means to come up with some explicit sets $A,B,C,D$ that violate the reverse inclusion. To get some intuition as to why this reverse inclusion is false, try sketching a picture. In the Cartesian plane, take $A,B,C,D$ to be closed intervals so that their Cartesian product is a rectangle. What we're basically doing is the set equivalent for why:
$$
(w - x)(y - z) \neq wy - xz
$$

Answer (score 1):

I found this that I think explains it well, "http://www.millersville.edu/~bikenaga/math-proof/counter/counter.html"

```
Example. To disprove the statement

"All professors like pizza"

you must find a professor who does not like pizza.

To disprove the statement

"For every real number x, $(x + 1)^2 = x^2 + 1$ "

 you must find a real number x for which $(x + 1)^2 does not equal x^2 + 1$ . 

So therefore in vice versa,

 To prove the statement
 (A∖B)×(C∖D)⊆(A×C)∖(B×D)

 so like what Henrik said, you must disprove the reverse inclusion statement, 
which is (A×C)∖(B×D) is a subset of (A∖B)×(C∖D), by making

(A×C)∖(B×D)⊈(A∖B)×(C∖D)
```

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly does it mean by "Show by way of a counterexample that the reverse inclusion is false"?

1. The "inclusion" mentioned in the previous sentence is
   $$(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)\subseteq(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D).$$
2. The "reverse inclusion" is
   $$(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)\supseteq(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$$
   or (equivalently)
   $$(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)\subseteq(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D);$$
   in words, $(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$ is a subset of $(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)$.
3. "[T]he reverse inclusion is false" means that $(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$ is **not necessarily** a subset of $(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)$.
4. "Show by way of a counterexample that the reverse inclusion is false" means "find sets $A,B,C,D$ such that $(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$ is not a subset of $(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)$."

> How would I go about solving this?

I would start by thinking about what the statement "$(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$ is not a subset of $(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)$" means.

5. It means, there is an element of $(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$ which is not an element of $(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)$.
6. An element of $(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$ is an element of $A\times C$ which is not an element of $B\times D$; in other words, an **ordered pair** $(x,y)$ which belongs to $A\times C$ but not to $B\times D$.
7. $(x,y)\in A\times C$ means that $x\in A$ **and** $y\in C$, while $(x,y)\notin B\times D$ means that $x\notin B$ **or** $y\notin D$.
8. $(x,y)\notin(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)$ means that $x\notin A\setminus B$ **or** $y\notin C\setminus D$.
9. Summing up, our requirements on $x$ and $y$ are:
   (i) $x\in A$;
   (ii) $y\in C$;
   (iii) $x\notin B$ or $y\notin D$;
   (iv) $x\notin A\setminus B$ or $y\notin C\setminus D$.
10. If $x\in A$ (so as to satisfy (i)), then the only way to satisfy $x\notin A\setminus B$ is by having $x\in B$. Likewise, if (ii) is satisfied, then $y\notin C\setminus D$ can be simplified to $y\in D$.
11. So the requirements on $x$ and $y$ are simplified to read:
    (i) $x\in A$;
    (ii) $y\in C$;
    (iii) $x\notin B$ or $y\notin D$;
    (iv) $x\in B$ or $y\in D$.
12. Conditions (iii) and (iv) leave us with a choice: either $x\notin B$ and $y\in D$, or else $x\in B$ and $y\notin D$. Let's try the first way: so now our requirements are:
    (i) $x\in A$;
    (ii) $y\in C$;
    (iii) $x\notin B$;
    (iv) $y\in D$.
13. Finally, let's define a concrete counterexample to the reverse implication. Let $x=1$ and $y=2$. We need $1\in A,\,2\in C,\,1\notin B,\,2\in D$, so let $A=\{1\}$, $\,B=\emptyset$, $\,C=\{2\}$, $\,D=\{2,\}$. Now we can verify that $(A\times C)\setminus(B\times D)$ is not a subset of $(A\setminus B)\times(C\setminus D)$ by observing that the element $(1,2)$ belongs to the former but not the latter.

That's how I would work this problem. Which step did you get stuck on?